# Finder crashes when trying to restore from Time Machine

Tags: finder, time-machine, restore

I'm on macOS Sierra 10.12.4. Using the Time Machine interface, I select a folder I want to restore (from an hour ago). The folder is located somewhere in my iCloud Drive folder. I select "Restore" and apparently Finder crashes. In Console, the following is logged:

```
default 08:32:07.878105 +0200   Finder  [WARNING] The gathering phase for children of '<private>' failed; error 22 (<private>)
default 08:32:08.117475 +0200   Finder  [WARNING] The gathering phase for children of '<private>' failed; error 22 (<private>)
default 08:32:08.905473 +0200   Finder  [WARNING] The gathering phase for children of '<private>' failed; error 22 (<private>)
default 08:32:12.601630 +0200   Finder  [WARNING] The gathering phase for children of '<private>' failed; error 22 (<private>)
default 08:32:13.644704 +0200   useractivityd   -- Demoting self.advertisingProcess to nil (was UserActivityClient(pid=20563/com.apple.finder uuids={}))
default 08:32:13.722481 +0200   Finder  got a connection for: com.apple.cache_delete
default 08:32:13.722690 +0200   Finder  got proxy: <private> for service: com.apple.cache_delete
default 08:32:13.723905 +0200   Finder  setting target uid to: 501 for service: com.apple.cache_delete
default 08:32:13.723933 +0200   Finder  connection invalidated
default 08:32:13.726826 +0200   Finder  got a connection for: com.apple.cache_delete
default 08:32:13.726986 +0200   Finder  got proxy: <private> for service: com.apple.cache_delete
default 08:32:13.727971 +0200   Finder  setting target uid to: 501 for service: com.apple.cache_delete
default 08:32:13.727995 +0200   Finder  connection invalidated
default 08:32:13.728481 +0200   Finder  got a connection for: com.apple.cache_delete
default 08:32:13.728587 +0200   Finder  got proxy: <private> for service: com.apple.cache_delete
default 08:32:13.729395 +0200   Finder  setting target uid to: 501 for service: com.apple.cache_delete
default 08:32:13.729418 +0200   Finder  connection invalidated
default 08:32:13.735007 +0200   Finder  got a connection for: com.apple.cache_delete
default 08:32:13.735290 +0200   Finder  got proxy: <private> for service: com.apple.cache_delete
default 08:32:13.736928 +0200   Finder  setting target uid to: 501 for service: com.apple.cache_delete
default 08:32:13.736952 +0200   Finder  connection invalidated
default 08:32:13.739246 +0200   Finder  <private> is not MNT_LOCAL!
default 08:32:13.739424 +0200   Finder  <private>
default 08:32:13.741101 +0200   Finder  <private> is not MNT_LOCAL!
default 08:32:13.741194 +0200   Finder  <private>
default 08:32:13.765183 +0200   Finder  discovered extensions
default 08:32:13.765334 +0200   Finder  discovered extensions
default 08:32:13.806805 +0200   Finder  <private> is not MNT_LOCAL!
default 08:32:13.806846 +0200   Finder  <private>
default 08:32:13.807627 +0200   Finder  got a connection for: com.apple.cache_delete
default 08:32:13.807771 +0200   Finder  got proxy: <private> for service: com.apple.cache_delete
default 08:32:13.809054 +0200   Finder  setting target uid to: 501 for service: com.apple.cache_delete
default 08:32:13.809085 +0200   Finder  connection invalidated
default 08:32:13.811485 +0200   UserEventAgent  Unregistered XPC Activity: com.example.finder.RemoveOldTrashItems
default 08:32:13.811980 +0200   UserEventAgent  Registered XPC Activity: com.example.finder.RemoveOldTrashItems
default 08:32:13.819238 +0200   Finder  .sdef warning for type 'unsigned integer' attribute 'id' of class 'window' in suite 'Window classes': AppleScript ID references may not work for this property because its type is not NSNumber- or NSString-derived.
default 08:32:13.819534 +0200   Finder  .sdef warning for type 'elsv' attribute 'name' of class 'column' in suite 'Type Definitions': AppleScript name references may not work for this property because its type is not NSString-derived.
default 08:32:13.972555 +0200   Finder  UNIX error exception: 17
default 08:32:13.972942 +0200   Finder  0x61800046d580 opened /private/var/db/mds/system/mdsDirectory.db: 50540 bytes
default 08:32:13.974469 +0200   Finder  UNIX error exception: 17
default 08:32:13.975045 +0200   Finder  UNIX error exception: 17
default 08:32:13.982766 +0200   Finder  MacOS error: -67050
default 08:32:13.982840 +0200   Finder  MacOS error: -67050
default 08:32:13.986836 +0200   Finder  Claim 3083D11B-96AD-4E6E-A687-A18FCB880145 granted in client
default 08:32:13.986875 +0200   Finder  Claim 3083D11B-96AD-4E6E-A687-A18FCB880145 invoked in client
default 08:32:13.990927 +0200   trustd  asynchronously fetching CRL (http://crl.apple.com/timestamp.crl) for client (Finder[20580])
default 08:32:13.991218 +0200   trustd  asynchronously fetching CRL (http://crl.apple.com/root.crl) for client (Finder[20580])
default 08:32:13.997549 +0200   Finder  MacOS error: -67050
default 08:32:13.997613 +0200   Finder  MacOS error: -67050
default 08:32:14.004115 +0200   Finder  MacOS error: -67050
default 08:32:14.004170 +0200   Finder  MacOS error: -67050
default 08:32:14.006245 +0200   Finder  MacOS error: -67062
default 08:32:14.006310 +0200   Finder  MacOS error: -67062
default 08:32:14.131752 +0200   Finder  [WARNING] could not find container for id: <private>
default 08:32:14.241962 +0200   Finder  Device supports AWDL
default 08:32:14.244776 +0200   Finder  ENCODE: Caching encoded userInfo to use until we are marked dirty again, returning encoded result <private> opts={ LSUserActivityContainsFileProviderURL = 0; LSUserActivityContainsUnsynchronizedCloudDocs = 0; UAUserActivityContainsCloudDocsKey = 0;}
default 08:32:14.245695 +0200   Finder  ENCODE: Caching encoded userInfo to use until we are marked dirty again, returning encoded result <private> opts={ LSUserActivityContainsFileProviderURL = 0; LSUserActivityContainsUnsynchronizedCloudDocs = 0; UAUserActivityContainsCloudDocsKey = 0;}
default 08:32:14.304482 +0200   Finder  SFBrowserCallBack (node = <SFNode 0x6080000e4980>{domain = Network})
```

Also when choosing "Restore to..." the same happens. What is going on, and how do I restore that folder?